# How to declare a variable then store a value for it later in a method?

Tags: java

If I declare a variable early on in a class, say double answer, can I assign it a value later on in another method, then recall that variable with that value in another instance? I'm unsure since it seems that the variable would be a local variable, and thus I can't recall it later in another method

Comment: Are you talking about the class static field?

Comment: Are you talking about a member variable ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)? If so, it's extremely common to store a value using a class method. It's called a setter method.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like two questions:

(1) If you declare a variable early in a class, and then later assign it a value inside a method, the assignment from the method will be effective.

(2) However it will not be effective to another *instance* of the class, unless the variable is static.  (Read about static variables here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)  You need to read about all the details, but the short versions is: if your variable is static it will have one value shared between all instances of your class.

Comment: Thanks; how do I make a variable static? I tried doing private static int variable, but it tells me it's an illegal modifier, and only final is allowed.